# JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <!DOCTYPE html> ^ when making a POST request with Postman Runner

Tags: json, api, postman, postman-collection-runner

While using Postman runner, I receive the below error when making a POST request.

I am trying to use the runner functionality in postman that takes in a CSV file. I have no issues making a single POST Request (no runner) with the following json Body:

```
{
   "column1":{
      "name":"testName"
   },
   "column2":[
      {
         "sNum":"testSerial",
         "type":"testType",
         "views":[
            {
               "name":"testName",
               "label":"NAME"
            },
            {
               "name":"testName2",
               "label":"NAME2"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "sNum":"1234",
         "type":"testType2",
         "views":[
            {
               "name":"John1",
               "label":"John"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My POST request will then return an ID, this is a unique ID that is a row in a table I am using the api for data insertion. However, I am using Postman runner because I want to make multiple Post calls - I have a big data set I need inserted into the DB. I have modified the POST request to:

```
{
    "column1": {"name": {{col1}}},
    "column2": [{{col2}}]
}
```

Col1 and Col2 are the column names of csv file the runner will intake. The request body will effectively be:

```
{
    "column1": {"name": "testName"},
    "column2": [{"sNum": "testSerial","type": "testType","views": [{"name": "testName","label": "NAME"},{"name": "testName2","label": "NAME2"}]},{"sNum":"1234","type":"testType2","views":[{"name":"John1","label":"John"}]}]
}↵↵
```

However when I run the runner it fails. The error I receive is "JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1

^" and the response body I get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /v1/installs</pre>
</body>
</html>↵
```

with console showing: POST https://linkgoeshere.com 404 50 ms

Why do I receive this html error? Any help is greatly appreciated, if more information is needed I can provide it. Thanks

Comment: The response body is indicating that the file you attempted to POST to doesn't exist. You should check the URL...

Comment: @Nick I am able to make successful post requests with the same url, is there a reason why it won’t work in this case?

Comment: There shouldn't be... are you sure you don't have a typo in this code? Check the network tab in your developer tools to make sure you're posting to the url you expect to.

Answer (score -2):

just check once request type is GET or POST. program and postman should have same request type

Answer (score -3):

It might have to do with a typo. Make sure you have added https:// at the start of your url. It worked for me.